# Twitter API version 2

Tags: php, twitter

I have been posting tweets via php scripts for a while.  VERSION 1.1.

Now I need to post tweets with the new Twitter API version 2.

The implementations I have tried use composer to create a composer.json file in the project directory that I think points to the source for the php api interface.

I have a very old version of Centos 6.3  and very old version of php 5.3.3.  when I try to use composer to create the json file with require the library.....I get an error that I have determined is caused by the particular version of php.  So I never get the composer.json file. (noweh/twitter-api-v2-php).

Can anyone tell me if I can make this work without using composer?

Does not seem to be an upgrade for php which may help.

I may have to get a new platform with newer linux going but thought if I could get tweets going it would give me time to create a new box.

Thanks.

## composer require noweh/twitter-api-v2

Your version of PHP, 5.3.3, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.

[LogicException]
ComposerRepository: Undefined $data. Please report at
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/new.

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

I found a discussion on composer.org about version php 5.3.3.that talked of a problem but never came to a tested solution.

Comment: The very first version of `noweh/twitter-api-v2` had a minimum requirement of PHP 7.3. It's not going to work on 5.3. https://github.com/noweh/twitter-api-v2-php/blob/a4ff29efe534dc4378f65d25d69f959fa43559cd/composer.json

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using PHP `5.3`. Its support [ended almost a decade ago](https://www.php.net/eol.php).

At the time of writing, you should upgrade to PHP `8.2`.

The same goes for your OS distro.